# passing history props to the dynamic created routes wrapped in a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i pass the history to the dynamically created routes which are 
wrapped with a another component

see the below snippet

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Loader from './Loader';
import RootComponent from './RootComponent';
import About from './About';
import Contact from './Contact';

class App extends Component{
  state = {
    loaderStatus: false,
    dynamicRoutes: null
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
      loaderStatus: true
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let routes = () => {
      let accessedRoutes = [{path:'about', component: () => <About />},{path:'contact', component: () => <Contact />}].map(o => {
        return (
          <Route
            exact={true}
            path={o.path}
            component={o.component}
          >
          </Route>
        )
      })
      return accessedRoutes
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      let output = this.createRoutes(routes)
      this.setState({
        dynamicRoutes: output,
        loaderStatus: false
      })
    }, 4000)
  }

  createRoutes = (routes) => {
    return (
      <RootComponent>
        <Switch>
          {routes}
        </Switch>
      </RootComponent>
    )
  }


  render(){
    return(
    <Fragment>
    {
      this.state.loaderStatus ?
      <Loader />
      :
      <Router>
        {this.state.dynamicRoutes}
      </Router>
    }
    </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

// About.js

```
import React from 'react';

const about = (props) => {
  console.log('props in about', props) // giving empty object
  return (
    <div>About</div>
  )
}

export default about
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the structure of accessedRoutes to [{path:'about', component:About}].
now you can access to the router props

Comment: that worked for me. Thanks for the response :), but what was the reason

Comment: the reason was you were passing an anonymous function to route when route trigger any component it call provided component function with route props, which you were not  receiving nor passing to About component

in your way, you can also do this.

[{path:'about', component:( route_props )=> <Abount { ...route_props } />  }  ].